# Submenu of a wxMenuItem

Tags: wxwidgets, submenu

I wanted to have a submenu manually append to a submenu("History") under "Edit"

```
wxMenuBar * menubara = GetMenuBar();
wxMenu * menua = menubara->GetMenu(1);
wxInt32 menuIda = menua->FindItem(wxT("History"));    
wxMenuItem * menuItema = menua->FindItem(menuIda);
```

This is how I get History as a wxMenuItem. However, there is no addSubMenu for wxMenuItem. How can I add a submenu to History?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my memory, so I might be wrong: you have to create another menu (if it does not already have it, get it with GetSubMenu), insert a new menu item for the new entry and use wxMenuItem->SetSubMenu to set it.

Comment: `wxMenu menuaa;
menuaa.Append(ID_EDITOR_TIMELINE, wxT("Delete"));
menuItema->SetSubMenu(& menuaa); `This is what I have done. But it still not working.

Comment: So I guess you should have 'History' as a submenu then.

Comment: It works, I used wxMenu menuaa = GetSubmenu() instead of just declear wxMenu menuaa. Thanks a lot.